# Как преобразовать значения словаря из str в int и вывести ключ с максимальным значением?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь, в котором значения это str. Далее нужно получить на выходе ключ с максимальным значением. Как это можно реализовать?

```py
di = {'Python разработчик': '150000', 
        'Data Scientist': '200000', 
        'Программист Python': '40000', 
        'Python разработчик (Django)': '140000', 
        'Backend Python / Django разработчик (удаленно)': '50000'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_max_key(data):
    max_key = None
    for key in data:
        if (max_key is None):
            max_key = key
            max_value = int(data[key])
        elif (max_value <= int(data[key])):
            max_key = key
            max_value = int(data[key])
    return max_key


di = {
    'Python разработчик': '150000',
    'Data Scientist': '200000',
    'Программист Python': '40000',
    'Python разработчик (Django)': '140000',
    'Backend Python / Django разработчик (удаленно)': '50000'
}

print(find_max_key(di))
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
ma = (max(di, key=di.get))
print(f'{ma}: {di[ma]}')
```